# Laravel Blade @yield is not working inside included view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to make layout using blade but the problem is that when i tried to 
@yield on the file which is included in master file but @yield is not working.

**resouces/views/layouts/app.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
...
...
</head>
<body>

@include('layouts.navigation')

@include('layouts.main_panel')

@include('layouts.footer')
</body>
</html>
```

**resouces/views/layouts/main_panel.blade.php**

```
// some html stuff 
@yield('form')
// some html stuff
```

**resouces/views/auth/login.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app') 

@section('form')
<form>
// input
</form>
@endsection
```

Comment: please shoü your folder structure

Comment: Is there an error or the @yield is view like normal text?

Comment: The code is right, there is no problem with it.

Comment: there is no error nor it is showing like normal text

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade I have updated the question with full path of view files

Comment: @HumairaNaz see my answer if it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you **pass variables** to the partials and **echo**
 them inside it. This is an alternative way to achieve what you are
 trying to do.

**For example -**

Partial blade file (resouces/views/partials.header.blade.php) -

```
<h4>{{ $name }}</h4>
```

View (resouces/views/custom.blade.php) -

```
@include('partials.header', [ 'name' => 'Lorem Ipsum' ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also using laravel framework but i used to do in that way :-

Layout :- **resouces/views/layouts/app.blade.php**

```
<html>
<head>
 ...
 ...
</head>
<body>

 @include('layouts.navigation')

 @yield('content') // use @yield here why you need separate file 

 @include('layouts.footer')
</body>
</html>
```

After that :- **resouces/views/auth/login.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app') 
@section('content')
<form>
   // input
</form>
@stop
```

Hope it helps!.. I used to follow this structure in laravel project